# Lex/Flex: Why do I get "error: request for member ‘str’ in something not a structure or union" when using --bison-locations

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I'm writing a parser for a fairly simple language. The language will allow describing a game that has rooms. Rooms contain "characters" and "things". Characters have "options" that allow you to interact with them; options can form a tree allowing multiple branches after you start interacting with a characrter.

I went through a few iterations and asked some questions and eventually got my parser to compile. But when I ran it on a sample input, I got syntax errors with no indication of what line the error was on.

I used my google-fu and found the flag --bison-locations that is supposed to generate code that will keep yylloc filled with the current line number.

But when I turn on that flag, I start getting 
"request for member ‘str’ in something not a structure or union"
messages.

With the flag off, my parser compiles but doesn't tell me where syntax errors are.

How can I get location information in yylloc without breaking the connection between my %union and my {semantic code...}?

My source and the log from make is at:
http://apdamien.info/code/GHparser.zip

Comment: We're not going to download an arbitrary `.zip` file. Find a way to reproduce the problem with the smallest amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want line number information, then specify `%option yylineno` in your (f)lex file and declare `extern int yylineno` in your yacc/bison file. flex will fill in `yylineno` automatically. If you want complete line number/column information, as in the `yylloc` struct, and you want it associated with each token where you can get at it in bison using `@n`, then you will have to do (a lot) more work, because flex does not fill in (or even compute) column numbers.

So `--bison-bridge` does not do what you think it does, and it probably doesn't do what you want. Maybe Google foo'd you to the page of *Taco Joe's Enchiladas and Flex Misconceptions* instead of the [appropriate section of the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Options-Affecting-Scanner-Behavior.html#index-yylineno), or it maybe it just foo'd you to the [appendix on bison-bridge](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Bison-Bridge.html) which you would  need to read very carefully because, while it is indeed the case that `--bison-locations` changes the calling convention for `yylex`, the important difference is not emphasized as much as it could be.

Perhaps the flex documenters made the assumption that people will understand the compiler error which will necessarily be produced if they use this option without adjusting their flex actions.

Anyway, the important point is:

> Note that the macros 'yylval' and 'yylloc' evaluate to pointers.

In other words, when you specify `--bison-bridge` (or `--bison-locations`. which implies `--bison-bridge`), `yylval` is no longer a global variable; instead, `yylex` is called with a *pointer* to the semantic value object, and `yylval` is thus of type `YYSTYPE*` rather than `YYSTYPE`. That means that you need to change any use of `yylval` in a flex action from, for example,

```
yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
```

to

```
yylval->str = strdup(yytext);
```

(By the way, if your action says `yylval.str = yytext;`, you need to search for one of the many SO answers to the questions like "why does the string value of my token change in the parser?", or read [this bison FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html#Strings-are-Destroyed). Or you could just use `strdup` as above, but I have the old-fashioned idea that one should *understand* the tools one is using, rather than just blindly copying code from anonymous strangers.)

Comment: Thanks, rici. That solved the problem completely. And I'll go read the FAQ and start using strdup, thanks.